# Leetcode 662: maximum width of binary tree in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I have the following solution to [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-width-of-binary-tree/). The idea is to compute the maximum width of a binary search tree. The width of a BST on a particular depth is defined as the distance from the leftmost non-null node to the rightmost non-null node at that depth. This implementation proceeds downwards from the root node in breadth-first manner keeping track of the width of the widest tree level until an empty level is encountered. (Note that the widest level isn’t necessarily the deepest one.

```
class TreeNode {
     int val;
     int num;
     TreeNode left;
     TreeNode right;
     TreeNode() {}
     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
         this.val = val;
         this.left = left;
         this.right = right;
     }
 }

class Solution {
    
    public int widthOfBinaryTree(TreeNode root) {
        TreeNode[] levelHi = new TreeNode[3_000];
        TreeNode[] levelLo = new TreeNode[3_000];
        levelHi[0] = root;
        
        root.num = 0;
        int maximumWidth = 1;
        int levelLength = 1;
        
        while (true) {
            int numberOfChildrenInLoLevel = 
                    getNextDeepestLevel(levelHi, levelLo, levelLength);
            
            if (numberOfChildrenInLoLevel == 0) {
                return maximumWidth;
            }
            
            int tentativeWidth = levelLo[numberOfChildrenInLoLevel - 1].num -
                                 levelLo[0].num + 1;
            
            maximumWidth = Math.max(maximumWidth, tentativeWidth);
            TreeNode[] levelTemp = levelLo;
            levelLo = levelHi;
            levelHi = levelTemp;
            levelLength = numberOfChildrenInLoLevel;
        }
    }
    
    int getNextDeepestLevel(TreeNode[] levelHi, 
                            TreeNode[] levelLo, 
                            int levelHiLength) {
        int levelLoLength = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < levelHiLength; i++) {
            TreeNode currentTreeNode = levelHi[i];
            TreeNode leftChild = currentTreeNode.left;
            TreeNode rightChild = currentTreeNode.right;
            
            if (leftChild != null) {
                leftChild.num = currentTreeNode.num * 2;
                levelLo[levelLoLength++] = leftChild;
            }
            
            if (rightChild != null) {
                rightChild.num = currentTreeNode.num * 2 + 1;
                levelLo[levelLoLength++] = rightChild;
            }
        }
        
        return levelLoLength;
    }
}
```

**Critique request**

I would like to hear comments about efficiency and space consumption.

Comment: I think your solution is optimal, for curiosity have you done some tests with a queue instead of the `TreeNode` two arrays (in case of sparse  tree with lot of a null nodes maybe could be a difference) ?

Comment: @dariosicily Nice suggestion, but currently not my top priority. I might give your idea a try in a week or so.

Comment: You consume way to much memory when the Tree is very small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just mention [doc comments](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html#styleguide),
and that you added an instance data member `num` to `TreeNode` as provided by LeetCode.

The code has illuminative names for most everything, but uses one *magic number*: 3000.

`getNextDeepestLevel()` has code duplicated in handling left and right child.
Not trivial to avoid in a language not supporting data aliasing
(C++: `TreeNode children[2], &left = children[0], &right = children[1];`),
but modifying `TreeNode`, anyway, one might implement `Iterable`. (I'll have to revisit [AspectJ](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/master/docs/dist/doc/README-197.html).)

**Efficiency**:
With the information provided in LeetCode 662, every node needs to be visited. With considerable overhead, I think it possible to reduce that to ⅔
• keeping a count of nodes in levels traversed *and*
• making use of knowledge about the tree's total number of nodes.
(What information would be needed to *just follow left and right boundaries*?
*node height* may help.)

**Space consumption**:
Each of the "level arrays" will need to keep no more than the *maximum number of nodes per level* -
which, for a binary tree, is bounded by \$\lceil \frac{\#nodes}2 \rceil\$.
For every other node added to `levelLo`, there is one node from `levelHi` no longer needed:
One can "overlay the arrays", e.g., filling from the high index end consuming nodes from lower index to zero, reversing roles&directions between passes/levels.
Or add *not keeping leaf nodes* to the picture, reducing the number of nodes *kept* per level to no more than one third of their total number. (And impeding code simplicity/brevity/readability: maintainability.)
[dariosicily mentioned](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/273016/leetcode-662-maximum-width-of-binary-tree-in-java#comment538980_273016) using a queue (the usual way of handling *level order*) - the number of nodes to handle in any given level is the size of the queue just after consuming the last node of the level before.

You are aware of *iterative deepening*.
When *not* keeping nodes with less than two children (and keeping the depth of nodes), this reduces *additional* space to \$O(\log n)\$ - increasing time drastically (to \$O(N^2)\$?).